# Python, how can I get access to the child class from it's parents metaclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

I essentially would like to do the following:

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

class A:

    def __init__(self, C):
        self._C = C

    async def get(self):
        print(">>> ", self._C.properties)


class BMeta:

    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("cls: ", cls)
        print("args: ", args)
        print("try: ", type(*args))
        cls._c = "I am class C"

    @property
    def objs(cls):
        return A(C=cls._c)


class B(metaclass=BMeta):
    pass


class C(B):
    pass


async def run():
    await C.objs.get()


loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

My question is, in the `__init__` of the metaclass, how can I make sure that the property `objs` is passing the class C into the init of class A? If I run the above, I get the following output:

```
cls:  <__main__.BMeta object at 0x7f5412770910>
args:  ('B', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'B'})
try:  <class '__main__.B'>
cls:  <__main__.BMeta object at 0x7f54127c8ed0>
args:  ('C', (<__main__.BMeta object at 0x7f5412770910>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'C'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 89, in <module>
    class C(B):
  File "test2.py", line 77, in __init__
    print("try: ", type(*args))
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I cannot make sense of this error message, and reading around I have not yet seen ways to do this..

Comment: I am guessing by calling `type(*args)` you are trying to dynamically create a new class `C` that will be bounded to the newly created class definition bound to `cls._c`?  Though the provided example is rather confusing because there is also a `class C` defined at the root level that will not necessarily be the same thing... Also another mistake is that `BMeta` must subclass from `type`, i.e.  must be declared with `class BMeta(type):`, in order for `BMeta` to be a proper metaclass (as it is, `B` is not actually a class, but an instance of `BMeta`).

Comment: It would also be useful to update your question to include example output, such as what `A._C` should equal to, or how does `C.objs` get populated, and that the `async` code shouldn't be used here as that does not appear to be the point of focus of this question.

Comment: Anyway, by ensuring that `BMeta` be subclassing from `type` (i.e. creating the metaclass correctly), the implicit `cls` provided to `BMeta.__init__` will be the correct class instances (`<class '__main__.C'>`), which appears to be what you want?

Comment: ahhhh, that helped alot. I have not used the `metaclass=` syntax before, and did not realise the metaclass should inherit `type`. Doing this, I can remove the metaclass `__init__`, and directly pass `cls` into A(C=cls) in the property `objs`. Thanks very much!